# Python: Trivial Attribute Error

Tags: python, attributeerror

**FIXED: Had to restart editor after editing and saving an imported module... Do I have to do this every time? I am using Enthought Canopy (64 bit)**

I am just starting out with Python classes today and was wondering why I am getting an Attribute Error after I try to call returnPlot() from my Stock class. pricePlot() works.

I have checked the indentation over and over again and retabbed everything, but I am sure it is going to be some silly problem.

Here is Stock.py:

```
class Stock:

    # Graphically presents the time trends of prices of the stock
    def pricePlot(self):
        ## Download the data
        dataFrame = self.priceDownload()
        ...


    # Graphically presents the time trends of the return of the stock
    # Parameter: Interval - the change in time; represented in days
    def returnPlot(self, interval):
        ## Download the data
        dataFrame = self.priceDownload()

        ## Get the x-values we will be using
        xAxis = [dataFrame[0][0]]
        index = interval
        while(index < len(dataFrame[0])):
            xAxis.append(dataFrame[0][index])
            index=index+interval

        ## Compute the return
        returns = [0]
        index = interval
        while(index < len(dataFrame[2])):
            returns.append(np.log2(dataFrame[2][index]/dataFrame[2][index-interval]))
            index=index+interval

        ## Plot the return
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        yAxis = returns

        ## Date setting
        months = date.MonthLocator()
        years = date.YearLocator()
        fmt = date.DateFormatter("%Y")

        plt.plot_date(xAxis, yAxis,'-')

        ## Configure the x-axis
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
        ax.autoscale_view()
        ax.grid(True)
        fig.autofmt_xdate()

        ## Add text description to the figure
        plt.xlabel("Date")
        plt.ylabel("Return")
        plt.title('Returns of ' + self.ticker)

        plt.show()

        ## Save the figure
        full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        path, file = os.path.split(full_path)
        plt.savefig(path + '\\' + self.ticker + 'returns.pdf')
```

Here is main.py - the code that calls the Stock class:

```
import Stock as s


myStock = s.Stock("VFINX")

myStock.pricePlot()    ## WORKS
myStock.returnPlot(5)  ## THROWS ERROR
```

And here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
main.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 myStock.pricePlot()
----> 7 myStock.returnPlot(5)

AttributeError: Stock instance has no attribute 'returnPlot'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and shorten it so that it includes only the code that is necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Could you post your code for returnplot.

Comment: This looks like an indentation error to me. Are you sure that your def returnPlot is under your stock class

Comment: @Nick: It's right under the pricePlot() function as shown.

Comment: It is to be indented at the same level as the `pricePlot` function

Comment: @Bhargav, just checked again. Indentation is the exact same in the source code.

Comment: Can you fix your code here?

Comment: @Bhargav, sorry, it was messed up. Forgot to indent after I pasted it here.

Comment: What output do you get from  `print(dir(mystock))` if you add it in main.py

Comment: @Nick, I get '['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'beginDate', 'endDate', 'priceDownload', 'pricePlot', 'ticker']'

Comment: Hmm, short of seeing the whole code for your file, I'm at a bit of a loss. It definitely looks like it's a subtle syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I even try adding  a simple printer() function and I get an Attribute Error. Can anyone else test out the whole code (available in original post) and see if it works for them?

Comment: For me it works, try reloading the python instance (if you're working in an interactive session).

Comment: Actually, after looking at your main code, you can see this is not the same code. If you want to pass Stock an argument, you have to have a `__init__` method defined in the Stock class.

Comment: Closing the editor and reopening it worked... there goes a solid 2 hours of my life. Do I have to restart the editor every time I make a simple code edit to an imported module?!

Comment: of course you need to reload the module, @PeterKuebler.  `python` doesn't continuously re-read the module file, updating any changes you make to it.  it reads the module file once when you import it.  if you're in `ipython`, you can reload a module after editing it with `reload(module)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were running main.py from the command line...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect `python` to continuously re-read each of your imported modules, and update what's imported with any new changes to the files.  `python` reads each module file once at the time of the `import`.

If you're using `ipython`, you can reload a module after editing it with `reload(module)`, where `module` is the name of your module.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do an edition, you need reload your module. Example

```
from imp import reload
reload(s)
```

These lines are valid for any python terminal or code (not only suing ipython). More info about [imp module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/imp.html).